# How to mount folder with nonASCII (cyrillic) letters by systemd mount-unit?

Tags: systemd, fstab, systemd-mount

I want to create systemd mount-unit equivalent for next `fstab` line

```
/dev/sdc1 /жышы ext4 defaults 1 2
```

Something as
**жышы.mount**

```
[Unit]
Description= /dev/sdc1 to /жышы

[Mount]
What=/dev/sdc1
Where=/жышы
Type=ext4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Yes, I tried to use `systemd-escape` for unit file name and for `Where`, but without success. My better approach was:
**xd0xb6xd1x8bxd1x88xd1x8b.mount**

```
[Unit]
Description= /dev/sdc1 to /жышы

[Mount]
What=/dev/sdc1
Where='/жышы'
Type=ext4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This variant almost working *(no error for unit file name)*, but mounts **/dev/sdc1** to auto-created folder **/xd0xb6xd1x8bxd1x88xd1x8b** instead of **/жышы.**

Please help to fix this mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man systemd.mount`:

> Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they control. Example: the mount point /home/lennart must be configured in a unit file home-lennart.mount. For details about the escaping logic used to convert a file system path to a unit name, see `systemd.unit(5)`.

OK, so from `man systemd.unit`:

> The escaping algorithm operates as follows: given a string, any "/" character is replaced by "-", and all other characters which are not ASCII alphanumerics, ":", "_" or "."  are replaced by C-style "\x2d" escapes. In addition, "."  is replaced with such a C-style escape when it would appear as the first character in the escaped string.
>
> When the input qualifies as absolute file system path, this algorithm is extended slightly: the path to the root directory "/" is encoded as single dash "-". In addition, any leading, trailing or duplicate "/" characters are removed from the string before transformation. Example: /foo//bar/baz/ becomes "foo-bar-baz".
>
> This escaping is fully reversible, as long as it is known whether the escaped string was a path (the unescaping results are different for paths and non-path strings). The `systemd-escape(1)` command may be used to apply and reverse escaping on arbitrary strings. Use `systemd-escape --path` to escape path strings, and `systemd-escape` without `--path` otherwise.

So, we run

```
systemd-escape --path /жышы
```

and get

```
\xd0\xb6\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b
```

So, `\xd0\xb6\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b.mount` is the right file name. The backslashes are important!

Comment: Well `\xd0\xb6\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b.mount` on my `ext4` show as `xd0xb6xd1x8bxd1x88xd1x8b.mount` file and non working.  
But creating file `\\xd0\\xb6\\xd1\\x8b\\xd1\\x88\\xd1\\x8b.mount` that show as `\xd0\xb6\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b.mount` does the trick.

Comment: What "shows" IS what you created. So, I don't know *how* you attempted to create things (something broke the backslashes!), but that file name with the single backslashes is the right one.

Comment: It was `touch \xd0\xb6\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd1\x8b.mount`. Yes I forgоt about esc-sequences in filenames. My bad.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about! :) Ah, I'd try `touch "$(systemd-escape --path /жышы).mount"`